# mysqli_fetch_row() access a specific row in the sql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using the mysqli_fetch_row() function. I am able to move through the database, but I would like to start from a specific row.  Am I able to do this using this function?

Comment: mysql_fetch_rows() merely execute an SQL command. You can use your sql command to move to a particular record and fetch your data from that point.

Comment: With [`mysql_data_seek()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php) to move through the result resource, or use a your query's WHERE clause to avoid returning rows you don't want in the first place.

Comment: I suspect you are looking for [`LIMIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html#id939610)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use mysql_* functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Instead you should learn either [PDO](http://in.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://in.php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose.

Comment: @gopi1410 The OP does actually state he is using MySQLi, just in a procedural way. I tend to push PDO over MySQLi simply because of `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` et al, I can't be doing with being forced to use `bind_result()` for every single query.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [mysqli_result::data_seek()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php). This takes an int and puts you at that row.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
mysqli_data_seek($result, $startRow);//start row is whatever you need to be the first row

while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
  //do your work here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, if you want to `LIMIT` the number off retrieved rows, or if you want to limit your query result with `WHERE` clause, or if you selected 100 rows you want to select row nr 10 of the result set etc...

> mysqli_fetch_row($result);

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM testTable";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    //Do stuff here
}
```

The function is designed to fetch one row of a result set that has already been queried for.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the LIMIT syntax in your query

http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm

Comment: I think this is only true if it's always true the first n rows are to be skipped. That information may not be available before the query is executed, or may change depending on the result set.